# Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, polyfills

I'm using CSS multi-column layout (css3) which of course works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari.
But many still use IE9 and we have a requirement to support it.

For IE support I include `csscolumns` polyfill js from [this site](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn).

When this polyfill loads in IE9 I get this error message in the console:

```
'unable to get value of the property 'indexof' object is null or undefined'
```

And the debugger highlights this code as the problem source:

```
function loadCssCache(s,callback){if(s.href.indexOf(location.host)==-1||s.href.indexOf(location.host)>50){return false}
```

And the code that calls `loadCssCache` is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    loadCssCache(document.styleSheets[i], "parseStylesheets")
}
```

`s.href.indexOf` is where it fails. Has anyone else run into this problem? Or may know what the problem can be?

Comment: The clue is in the error message

Comment: The problem isn't with `indexOf`, the error message says that `s.href` is null or undefined. You need to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-DocumentStyle-styleSheets) seems to indicate that inline stylesheets (the content contained within a `style` attribute) are included in the `document.styleSheets` list. The relevant part is probably this:

> For inline style sheets, the value of this attribute is null.

So, if you have any style attributes on any elements, you're going to get a null-reference error when trying to read a value off `.href`.

A simple fix is to add a check for `null`:

```
function loadCssCache(s,callback){
    if(s.href == null || s.href.indexOf(location.host) == -1 || s.href.indexOf(location.host) > 50){
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I use no inline style on the div with csscolumns, only "height" inline style on another div for animation purposes. A solution could be to update the href manually for those that are null.

Comment: @gorn `document` refers to the entire page, so if *any* element has an inline style, it will be included. You can see what your browser is trying to parse by adding a `console.log(document.styleSheets)` to one of your `script` elements.

Comment: Yes, `document.styleSheets[0]` is a good way to test it. The problems was that I loaded the script too early. The css wasn't ready :|